# IntegrityError at /signup UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username ---> In django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

When I click on sign in button I get integrity error!! I have checked in my admin site and all users are properly visible which I had signed up. But when I click sign in button with entries already registered in admin, my code crashes and gives integrity error!!

views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render , HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate , login




# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request,"authentication/index.html")
def signup(request):
    if request.method=="POST": 
        username=request.POST.get('username')
        fname=request.POST.get('fname')
        lname=request.POST.get('lname')
        email=request.POST.get('email')
        pass1=request.POST.get('pass1')
        pass2=request.POST.get('pass2')
        myuser=User.objects.create_user(username,email,pass1) #creating user
        myuser.first_name=fname
        myuser.last_name=lname
        myuser.save() 
        messages.success(request,"Your account has been successfuly created")
        return redirect('/signin')


    return render(request,"authentication/signup.html")

def signin(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        username=request.POST.get('username')
        pass1=request.POST.get('pass1')
        user=authenticate(username=username,password=pass1) 
        if user is not None: 
            login(request,user)
           
            return render(request,"authentication/index.html")
        else:
            messages.error(request,"Bad credentials") 
            redirect('home')


    return render(request,"authentication/signin.html")
def signout(request):
    pass
```

Comment: As the error suggests, there already is a User with that username, Django auth requires a unique username..

Comment: Are you  using inbuilt `User` model or you have customized it using `AbstractUser` or `AbstractBaseUser`, can you please clarify?